Failing to link with clangTooling on some linux versions
I have a project that uses clang tooling. The CMake file for the project is something like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(clangToolingProject LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG)
separate_arguments(LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

add_library(clangToolingTestLib test.cpp)
target_include_directories(clangToolingTestLib PRIVATE ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(clangToolingTestLib PRIVATE ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST})
target_link_libraries(clangToolingTestLib
    LLVM
    clangTooling
)

On some linux machines this works, but on one linux image I get this error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangTooling
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So I fail to link with clangTooling. The issue is I think that I have the required lib on the image (although I'm not sure). cmake find_package doesn't fail, so it seems like it finds Clang but it is not able to link with it.
When I try to find libClangTooling on my image I'm not able to find it:
ldconfig -p | grep clangTooling

But this is the same also for images that are able to compile this project. So I assume somehow find_package add something to the link path (or something like that).
The image that doesn't work is RockyLinux 8.8.

"So I assume somehow find_package add something to the link path" - No, your assumption is wrong. Call to find_package normally sets some variables or targets, against which you could link with. You don't use these variables (or targets) in your code, so no link paths are added when your project is built. If you wonder about the location of libraries found by find_package, then CMake prints where the config script is found. The libraries are located in the same subtree (e.g. config script is under share/cmake/ subdirectory, and libraries are under lib/ subdirectory).

What you are saying doesn't make sense, because on the linux images the build does work on, when I remove the line find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG) I get the same error of failing to link, so this line does effect linking.
Is there a way to see that code that runs when I call find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG)? Because I'm not able to find any such file under share/cmake.

Most likely, on a machines which has clangTooling installed, find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG) provides the target with that name. But on machines which lacks for given library, the target is not provided. You could check existence of the target in CMake script by using if(TARGET clangTooling) construction. "Is there a way to see that code that runs when I call find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG)?" - CMake executes ClangConfig.cmake script. Path to that script is printed by CMake when it processes corresponding find_package call.
